# how to load a Disqus profile in .NET MAUI?

Tags: maui, user-accounts, disqus

Is it possible to load the profile picture/name of the currently logged in Disqus account in your .NET MAUI application?
if so, how do you do it?

I have been trying to do it for a while now but I keep finding websites that **USE** Disqus instead of telling how to implement it.

Comment: how is your MAUI app supposed too know what your "currently logged in Disqus" account is?

Comment: It's already possible to connect your google account, so I think it should be possible to do the same thing with Disqus (I am not sure about it but it sounds logical to me)

Comment: if you are talking about using Google auth in a MAUI app, that is a specific auth wortkflow that Google supports.  Does Disqus?  And its considerably more complex than just loading a profile image

Comment: I didn't know that, but I think it is supported since they do have a NuGet package, but its just difficult to use it